# in/on the showcase

Tags: prepositions

A showcase is a shelved container, but is usually enclosed. So do we put something on the showcase or in the showcase?

You could use this extract as an example to show the meaning of the word:

> The girl never blinked or turned aside. I was maybe twenty feet away; and her look was so strong, I had to glance down. **On the showcase beside me** was a pear-wood mandolin perfectly made. I strummed it once and tried to pretend I knew how to tune it. When I had it sounding halfway right, I looked again. Now the girl was smiling, and her mother was striding on towards me as if I'd made some last mistake.
>   [image]

You could always use your own everyday English for examples.

Comment: On the showcase = on the whole container? in the showcase= on the shelves?

Comment: We say that something is "on show" at a museum, where it will often be sitting behind glass, entirely enclosed. But a showcase can also be waist-high or chest-high, with an open top shelf on which items may sit. The passage you quote suggests as much, since the instrument was (apparently) accessible. He strummed it.  It the item is inside, it's "in" but if them item is on top, it's "on".

Comment: Thank you @TRomano. Let's suppose an article in on the middle shelf of a shelved showcase in a small store or better off a house , and you are telling your son "*Look there it is, it's **on/in** the showcase*"

Comment: Assuming the middle shelf (i.e. not sitting on top): if the showcase has glass doors that enclose the shelves, the article is *in the showcase*. If the showcase  has an open front without doors, the article is *on the showcase* or *on the showcase shelf*.

Comment: To really "split hairs", use "in" if there is a boundary of some type involved, even imaginary lines or borders.  Use "on" if there is an edge or surface of a boundary.  Something can be in the area marked by the boundary, or on a surface.

Comment: Hey @TRomano, why don't you make that comment an answer so this question can be answered and Learner can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take several of the comments and stitch them into a cohesive whole, here's a rule of thumb:

> If you can logically place something *within* the object you're referring to, place it ***in*** the showcase; if not, put it ***on*** the showcase.

To illustrate, allow me to introduce an example showcase called "the Wing."[image: Wing Glass Shelving]

- The metal figures at the upper left are ***on*** the showcase
- The glass vials filled with colored liquids on the top center shelf are ***in*** the showcase
- The tray containing two colored eggs on the right of the second shelf down are ***on*** the showcase
- The metal containers on the left of the third shelf down are ***on*** the showcase
- The glass panel on the center of the third shelf down is ***in*** the showcase
- The tall colored glass bottles on the center of the bottom shelf are ***in*** the showcase